# ColdFusion 9, Tomcat 7, Apache and vhosts

Tags: apache, tomcat, coldfusion

I've successfully managed to install CF9 (war) in Tomcat 7, linking the two via Apache vhosts. I'm using ajp to proxy .cfm requests, and other rewrite urls to Tomcat 7 with Apache serving the rest of the content.

However, each vhost needs its own copy of the ColdFusion WEB-INF in the vhost root. This works fine, but it has the side affect of each cf site having a unique instance of CF. The mappings, DSNs and all other settings are custom and not shared between the CF sites.

I'd really like to combine each WEB-INF so that they're is just one for my entire dev setup, kinda like how JRun4 used to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible with Tomcat as we have two separate instances and both separate installation files.

Comment: Yeah, even when I symlink (on Mac) the WEB-INF directory from a vhost root, to the cfusion/WEB-INF directory it still fires up individual instances of CF.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replicating the virtual hosts in Tomcat also? I found this on the Tomcat wiki which sounds like it answers your question.

http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/CreateVirtualHosts

Comment: Yep, I've successfully managed to get that working fine. This was a requirement because of the way I wanted to use ajp to remove the context in the URL path.So yeah, that's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Scott, I know this is an old thread. Did you manage to make it work, or even, is this still relevant? I was trying to do the same and found that you could make a symlink to the original ColdFusion context's META-INF and WEB-INF instead of copying the entire directory structures. Just remember to add `allowLinking="true"` in the `<Host>` tag in Tomcat's server.xml. So:

```
ln -s /path/to/tomcat/webapps/cfusion/META-INF /path/to/yourhost1/META-INF

ln -s /path/to/tomcat/webapps/cfusion/WEB-INF /path/to/yourhost1/WEB-INF

ln -s /path/to/tomcat/webapps/cfusion/META-INF /path/to/yourhost2/META-INF

ln -s /path/to/tomcat/webapps/cfusion/WEB-INF /path/to/yourhost2/WEB-INF
```

Basically all virtual hosts are indeed Java applications, but they share the same ColdFusion engine and ColdFusion meta-data so the DSN is shared across all hosts.

Now I'm not sure if above is a good practice, break anything, or worst, make kittens sad.

Any feedback is welcome.