# Is it possible to Create Symbolic Link with ColdFusion 2018 on Solaris/Linux server not using external script

Tags: coldfusion, solaris, symlink, coldfusion-2016

So I have the the current directory structure

```
/dir1 ---
    /(sym_link) <----
    file1.txt       |
    file2.txt       |
                    |
/dir2               |
    /(sym_link)<----|
    file3.txt       |
    file4.txt       |
                    |
/sym_link ----------|
   sym_file1.txt
   sym_file2.txt
```

I have been investigating using [`<cffile>`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-f/cffile.html) and [`<cfdirectory>`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-d-e/cfdirectory.html) to try generate a symbolic link on a Solaris Server ( There doesn't seem to be any documentation about working with symbolic links on these tags.. or really in general)

I am aware I can run a script on the server and generate them external of ColdFusion with `<cfexecute>` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21013065/creating-a-symbolic-link-with-coldfusion)

Curious I manually created a Symbolic Link in `/dir1` and did the following command

```
<cfdirectory action="list" directory="/dir1" recurse="false" name="myList">
<cfdump var="#myList#">
```

and  recieved

```
Attributes      DateLastModified      Directory Link    Mode        Name    Size Type
[empty string]  10/16/2018 09:38:53 PM  /dir1  YES  [empty string]  sym_link  2  Dir
[empty string]  10/17/2018 03:16:38 PM  /dir1  NO   [empty string]  file1.txt 0  File
[empty string]  10/17/2018 03:16:41 PM  /dir1  NO   [empty string]  file2.txt 0  File
```

I can see that ColdFusion recognizes it as a symbolic link!

However there doesn't seem to be any way to create a `DIR` with `Link` set to `YES` using `<cfdirectory action="create">`

(One approach I have been attempting to copy an existing symbolic link to where I need it, but haven't had much luck yet)

Is there anyway to create a symbolic link using **ONLY** ColdFusion and **not running** any scripts locally on the server?

Comment: The answer at the bottom of this seems similar to your concern: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435175/coldfusion-9-tomcat-7-apache-and-vhosts/16555822#16555822

Comment: It believe its a tad different in nature.... The answer at the bottom of the linked post describes an approach of using symlinks (created manually) to avoid duplicating WEB-INF when using two Apache vhosts ...  I'm asking about actually creating the symbolic links from within ColdFusion as opposed to just following them ... Thanks for the suggestion tho!

Comment: I don't know if CF supports it. If not, might try using java [Files.createSymbolicLink(Path, Path)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19543891/8895292). See also [Links, Symbolic and Otherwise](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/links.html).

Comment: I don't think CF supports it either. While searching for it I came across this blog post from Ben Nadel explaining that you need to configure Tomcat for ColdFusion to even use a symbolic link. Maybe it will help you but I'm guessing not. [ColdFusion 10 Beta, Apache Tomcat, And Symbolic Links On Mac OSX](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2330-coldfusion-10-beta-apache-tomcat-and-symbolic-links-on-mac-osx.htm)